# Google workplace: activate gmail via API

Tags: ruby, google-api, gmail-api, google-workspace

I need to automate some flow on google workspace, now I'm stuck at Activating Gmail via API, I couldn't find any resource or example anywhere.

Appreciate for any help pointing out the reference or answer.

Update:

So I have google workspace and I am working on automate user and their gmail account. From the screenshot I can simply click on "Activate Gmail" and it will check against my MX records and have it activated, but I'm looking for a solution where I can do it from google API using Ruby.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by activating gmail? Try to explain and visualize the main issue. Also what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For this one, you will most likely make use of Directory API's [`users.update`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/update) instead of Gmail API. Gmail API only enables you to access gmail settings and the emails, not the user settings.

Sadly, I haven't found any fields dedicated for activating/enabling Gmail. The closest thing I found was [`isMailboxSetup`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users#User), but it only identifies if the user have its Gmail activated.

> Indicates if the user's Google mailbox is created. This property is only applicable if the user has been assigned a Gmail license.

Given the circumstances above, you might need to do it manually. For more info regarding the subject, visit the reference below.

#### Reference:

- [Admin SDK: Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest)

Comment: Although it's not the answer, but thanks by the way.